# Extracting global variable value from brackets

Tags: postman

I am sending a POST request, which I'm getting in the response an attribute named "value" that its value is a number with brackets. I need to use the number without the brackets for my next API request.

Here is what I get in the response of my request:

```
{
    "additionalAttributes": {
        "map": [
            {
                "key": "RESULT_IDS",
                "value": "[26913648997439042205288611421953968843]"
            }
        ]
}
```

Here is what I've updated in Tests tab of the request in order to save it as a global variable:

```
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;


if (responseCode.code === 200) {
    try {
        var campaign_data = JSON.parse(responseBody),
            campaignValue = campaign_data.additionalAttributes.map[0].value;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    postman.setGlobalVariable("campaignValue",campaignValue);
}
```

Can you explain please how can I have the value 26913648997439042205288611421953968843 without the brackets saved into a global variable?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the integrated lodash lib of the Postman sandbox:

```
var campaignValueRaw = campaign_data.additionalAttributes.map[0].value;
var campaignValue = _.trimRight(_.trimLeft(campaignValueRaw, '[') , ']');
```